# Example of a linear operator has no continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Construct a linear mapping $T : X → Y$ between two normed linear spaces X
and Y such that T is one-to-one, onto, and continuous, but $T^
{−1}$
is not continuous.

I can not find any example because of linear mapping.

Thanks for any hint with that.

Comment: One of $X$ or $Y$ can't be complete. Try the identity on a well-known space of functions with different norms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T:l^{\infty}\rightarrow l^{2}$, $T:(x_{n})\rightarrow(x_{n}/n)$, consider $S:l^{\infty}\rightarrow T(l^{\infty})$ be the restriction of its codomain, then $S$ is continuous, one-to-one, and onto. Now consider the $e^{1},2e^{2},3e^{3},...$, where $e^{n}=(0,...,1,...,0,...)$ where $1$ is at the $n$th entry, then $\|ne^{n}\|_{l^{\infty}}=n\rightarrow\infty$ but $\|S(ne^{n})\|_{l^{2}}=1$.